# Unable to get async/await working in react native

Tags: react-native

I have not been able to get async/await working in a react native project.

```
const async getUser = () => {
  try{
    let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
    return value;
  }
  catch(e){
    throw e
  }
}
```

I always get an Unexpected token error. I have tried adding `{ "presets": ["react-native", "es2015", "babel-preset-stage-3"] }` with the same result.

On version `^0.35.0`

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for `async` arrow functions is:

```
const getUser = async () => {
  ...
}
```